# Server-Sent Events vs AJAX Polling vs WebSockets for Notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building simple notificiation system and I just wanted to know what is the best technique to use to do the job, right now I am doing AJAX requests to server every 30 secs per user to check for new notifications.Since this will be entertainment site it is not crucial for notifications to be pulled in realtime. My main concern is browser support, conserving server resources and scalability, so which technique would best fit the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060645/nodejs-vs-signalr-why-do-we-need-server-side-javascript

Comment: I saw video where Scott Gu presented SingnalR, it seems like best way to go but I'm interested on how it compares to other techniques. Mainly ajax polling.

Comment: ofcourse, SignalR uses a fallback system where it will be switched to Polling if the browser does not have Socket capability. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally

Comment: Wow that really is amazing. I will go with SinalR. Thanks!